# Optimal way to parse an if condition to extract variable names

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I have an if condition as a string and want to extract variable names.
Example 1:

```
Input: "((a>5 and b<20) or (c>30))"
Output: {"a", "b", "c"}
```

Example 2:

```
Input: "a==20"
Output: {"a"}
```

What is the best way to extract just the variable names?
Will regex work for this? The condition can be of any length.
I have also considered splitting on space and then trimming off unwanted characters till we arrive at just the variable name.

Comment: Have you written any code yet? If not, it is difficult for anyone to help.

Comment: I don't think the grammar for your conditions is regular, especially if they can be nested recursively. You could try writing a recursive descent parser or something similar, parse the entire condition into a tree, and then extract variable names from the leaves of the tree.

Comment: @RaghavMalik Will the tree build up time be an unnecessary overhead? Since I will be discarding the tree after extracting variable names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any Python-like identifier conforms to a well-defined regular expression:

```
ident = "[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*"
```

As long as you *do not have quoted strings*, you can find all identifiers in your expression and then remove all keywords (a list of them is closed), e.g.:

```
keywords = {"and", "or"} # Expand as needed
s = "((a>5 and b<20) or (c>30))"
[i for i in re.findall(ident, s) if i not in keywords]
#['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Beware that if a constant string is present (e.g., `'abc'`), it may be falsely recognized as a variable.

Comment: Can you explain how this will handle brackets and constants such as 5, 20 in example #1?

Comment: Brackets and constants do not match the regular expression.